# Passing an array as a value

Tags: arrays, c, function

I have the following function. I want it to sum all of the elements of the array passed to it. What am I missing??

```
int sum(int array[], int size) {

   int sum = 0;
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
   sum += array[i];
   return sum;
}
```

Comment: You didn't say what the problem is.

Comment: *"It happens this way in this language, so it must also happen the same way in that language.* -----> You can't learn C with trial and error. The dot operator doesn't do what you think it does here.

Answer (score 3):

As you are using `array.length` which is not a valid function on c, instead you can use `size` which is given as a argument to the function `sum`.

```
int sum(int array[], int size) {
    int sum = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        sum += array[i];
    return sum;
}
```